# How to disable kendo ui datepicker and Timepicker on view page

Tags: php, kendo-ui

I want to disable kendo ui DatePicker and TimePicker ,
My code is

```
$startTime = new \Kendo\UI\TimePicker('StartTime');
 $startTime->value('10:00')
     ->format('HH:mm')
    //->disabled(true)
   ->attr('name','data[Branch][StartTime]');
```

Please suggest me proper solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is

```
$dateTimePicker->value(new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('UTC')))
            ->attr('readonly', 'readonly') //value will be post
 //or
            ->attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //value wont be post
```

Answer (score 0):

After you

```
echo $startTime -> render();
```

...then you can use jQuery.  I don't think it is possible to render it disabled via the widget initialization.

```
$("#StartTime").prop('disabled',true);
```

Comment: ok thank you for your reply... I will make note of it when i have to use it in jquery... now i have to use simple ->attr('disabled', 'disabled'); property